# Extracting text from a PDF file using PDFMiner in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, text-extraction, pdfminer

I am looking for documentation *or* examples on how to extract text from a PDF file using PDFMiner with Python.

It looks like PDFMiner updated their API and all the relevant examples I have found contain outdated code(classes and methods have changed).  The libraries I have found that make the task of extracting text from a PDF file easier are using the old PDFMiner syntax so I'm not sure how to do this.

As it is, I'm just looking at source-code to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your answer so it is in a better format and aligns to the guidelines.

Comment: Which distribution of Python are you using, 2.7.x or 3.x.x? It should be noted that the author *explicitly* detailed that `PDFminer` doesn't work with Python 3.x.x. That might be the reason you're getting `import` errors. You should use `pdfminer3k` if so, as it is the standing Python 3 import of said library.

Comment: @Nanashi, sorry, I forgot to add my Python version.  It's 2.7 so that isn't the issue.  I have been looking through the source-code and it looks like they restructured some things which is why the imports are breaking.  I can't find any documentation for PDFMiner either or I would just be working off of that :(

Comment: I have just literally installed `PDFminer` off from GitHub and it imports fine. Can you kindly post your code and post your full error traceback as well?

Comment: @Nanashi, Like I said in my original question, the libraries that rely on PDFMiner break before finishing imports along with any example that I can find.  This is not a PDFMiner issue.  This is me looking for documentation, or an example of how to use PDFMiner.  Everything I can find is using an old syntax for PDFMiner.  I went ahead and edited my question for clarity.  I think I made it more confusing than it needed to be.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If that's the case, you're in for a downer: the docs are *very* sparse. The offline docs coming in with the GitHub download didn't even break 100KB. In addition, the Google user group is not active, I believe. If you're willing to brave the rather insufficient docs, here's the relevant [link](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html). A recommended example is [here](http://denis.papathanasiou.org/2010/08/04/extracting-text-images-from-pdf-files/) as well.

Comment: Admittedly, even the recommended example is outdated: it's from Jan 2012. The API, as you said, was updated March this year. If all else fails, it looks like you will have to port some of the functions yourself. I don't think it will be *that* difficult, but if entire class structures and methods were deprecated or changed, therein lies the problem. However, based on changelogs, it seems like the only real big change happened when the package was updated to accommodate 2.6 as the minimum, up from 2.4. Unless that's the level of update you need, I think it's pretty easy to port it.

Comment: @Nanashi, I'm trying to just point the imports in the examples to the right location to see if the methods retained their functionality.  Hopefully it will work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use pdfminer as a library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725278/how-do-i-use-pdfminer-as-a-library)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Here is a working example of extracting text from a PDF file using the current version of PDFMiner(September 2016)

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

PDFMiner's structure changed recently, so this should work for extracting text from the PDF files.

**Edit** : Still working as of the June 7th of 2018. Verified in Python Version 3.x

Edit: The solution works with Python 3.7 at October 3, 2019. I used the Python library `pdfminer.six`, released on November 2018.

Comment: works fine, but, how can I deal with spaces in for example names? suppose I have a pdf that contains 4 columns where I have first- and lastname in one col, now it get parsed with firstname in one row and lastname in one row, here's an example http://docdro.id/rRyef3x

Comment: Currently getting an import error with this code:

ImportError: No module named 'pdfminer.pdfpage'

Comment: @Jefe , make sur you run make install after downloading pdfminer.

Comment: works on ubuntu 16.04 as of February 1, 2017 - big thanks, finally sth that actually works :)

Comment: Thanks. Python 3 users might want to change `from cStringIO import StringIO` to `from io import StringIO`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18284900/701284

Comment: Thanks it works on python v2.7.12 and on ubuntu 16.04, though it would be better to load the pdf document with encoding utf-8, because my sample pdf has some encoding issue so try this after encoding with utf-8 and it resolve the issue... 
    `import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`

Comment: July, 19, 2017, still working on Python v2.7.12. Also, it's good to note that if you want HTML instead of plain text, you can switch `TextConverter` to `HTMLConverter`.

Comment: @DuckPuncher, Is it still working now? I had to change the `file(path, 'rb')` to `open(path, 'rb') to get mine to work.

Comment: Hi..When i'm trying to get data from pdf..using above code..i'm getting error saying. TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str' at interpreter.process_page(page)
Please help..if you are aware..thanks

Comment: Still working for Python3.7 users. Installed pdfminer.six==20181108 package. Best solution so far for my case and I compared numerous solutions.

Comment: Tried with `pdfminer.six==20181108` and `pdfminer.six==20200124` ; in both cases nothing is extracted except `\x0c`, although the doc is a simple dummy doc generated with word. Working with `Python 3.7`.

Comment: How can I does it get to work? Do I need to change inside the path in def convert_pdf_to_txt(path): with my directory path?

Comment: Check out below answer which works in May 2020 and is very simple: 
`from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text` then `text = extract_text('report.pdf')`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61857301/7483211

Comment: I got a "got an unexpected keyword argument 'codec'" error. It seems like the 'codec' parameter been since been removed. It worked when I removed the codec parameter from TextConverter(...)

Comment: I used same code on windows python 3.7 . Text extracted but all newlines are lost! Any idea?

Answer (score 34):

This works in May 2020 using PDFminer six in Python3.

##### Installing the package

```bash
$ pip install pdfminer.six
```

##### Importing the package

```py
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
```

##### Using a PDF saved on disk

```py
text = extract_text('report.pdf')
```

Or alternatively:

```py
with open('report.pdf','rb') as f:
    text = extract_text(f)
```

##### Using PDF already in memory

If the PDF is already in memory, for example if retrieved from the web with the requests library, it can be converted to a stream using the `io` library:

```py
import io

response = requests.get(url)
text = extract_text(io.BytesIO(response.content))
```

##### Performance and Reliability compared with PyPDF2

PDFminer.six works more reliably than PyPDF2 (which fails with certain types of PDFs), in particular PDF version 1.7

However, text extraction with PDFminer.six is significantly slower than PyPDF2 by a factor of 6.

I timed text extraction with `timeit` on a 15" MBP (2018), timing only the extraction function (no file opening etc.) with a 10 page PDF and got the following results:

```
PDFminer.six: 2.88 sec
PyPDF2:       0.45 sec
```

pdfminer.six also has a huge footprint, requiring pycryptodome which needs GCC and other things installed pushing a minimal install docker image on Alpine Linux from 80 MB to 350 MB. PyPDF2 has no noticeable storage impact.

**Update (2022-08-04)**: According to Martin Thoma, PyPDF2 has improved a lot in the past 2 years, so do give it a try as well. Here's his [benchmark](https://github.com/py-pdf/benchmarks)

Comment: PyPDF2 had a lot of improvements since this answer was given. Especially the text extraction was improved a lot. In [my benchmark](https://github.com/py-pdf/benchmarks) the text extraction of PyPDF2 is now better than the one of pdfminer

Answer (score 33):

terrific answer from DuckPuncher, for Python3 make sure you install pdfminer2 and do:

```
import io

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,
                                  password=password,
                                  caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)



    fp.close()
    device.close()
    text = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfminer.pdfpage' i am using python 3.6

Comment: @Atti, just in case, make sure that you have pdfminer2 installed, as there is another package pdfminer (I hate this). It works for pdfminer2==20151206 version when doing pip3 freeze.

Comment: thanks i got it working eventually, i installed pdfminer.six from conda forge

Comment: For Python 3, pdfminer.six is the recommended package - https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Comment: Is this still current. I'm getting the same `ImportError:` message

Comment: @Punter345: its current. Make sure you install "pdfminer2" not "pdfminer"

Comment: try installing pdfminer3.  this works for me under python 3.6 and pdfminer3 version 2018.12.3.0

Comment: Error from python 3.7 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'. Installing chardet using pip install chardet fixed this error.

Comment: Check out below answer which works in May 2020 and is very simple: 
`from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text` then `text = extract_text('report.pdf')`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61857301/7483211

Answer (score 29):

Full disclosure, I am one of the maintainers of [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six). It is a community-maintained version of pdfminer for python 3.

Nowadays, it has multiple api's to extract text from a PDF, depending on your needs. Behind the scenes, all of these api's use the same logic for parsing and analyzing the layout.

(All the examples assume your PDF file is called *example.pdf*)

**Commandline**

If you want to extract text just once you can use the commandline tool pdf2txt.py:

```sh
$ pdf2txt.py example.pdf
```

**High-level api**

If you want to extract text (properties) with Python, you can use the high-level api. This approach is the go-to solution if you want to programmatically extract information from a PDF.

```py
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

# Extract text from a pdf.
text = extract_text('example.pdf')

# Extract iterable of LTPage objects.
pages = extract_pages('example.pdf')
```

**Composable api**

There is also a composable api that gives a lot of flexibility in handling the resulting objects. For example, it allows you to create your own layout algorithm. This method is suggested in the other answers, but I would only recommend this when you need to customize some component.

```
from io import StringIO

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser

output_string = StringIO()
with open('example.pdf', 'rb') as in_file:
    parser = PDFParser(in_file)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

print(output_string.getvalue())
```

Similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70056092/4054971). I'll try to keep them in sync.

Comment: pdf2text should be imported from import tools.pdf2 module not the pdfminer.high_level

Answer (score 2):

this code is tested with pdfminer for python 3 (pdfminer-20191125)

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextBoxHorizontal

def parsedocument(document):
    # convert all horizontal text into a lines list (one entry per line)
    # document is a file stream
    lines = []
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(document):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
            layout = device.get_result()
            for element in layout:
                if isinstance(element, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                    lines.extend(element.get_text().splitlines())
    return lines
```

Comment: I have PDF files which I am able to convert using the Nitro Pro tool. When I try to convert the same PDF using the code posted here, however, I get output which suggests that there is a permissions error. Here is the output: ('from the SAGE Social Science Collections. All Rights Reserved.\n\n\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c')

Comment: What do you mean a file stream?

Comment: @Vincent with open(file,'rb') as stream: [...]

Comment: do you manage to get this file as a table/pandas ideally? https://www.groupe-psa.com/en/publication/monthly-world-sales-march-2020/

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old question.
For anyone trying to use pdfminer, you should switch to pdfminer.six which is the currently maintained version.

Comment: Or to PyPDF2 :-)