# Pdfminer python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, text, extract, pdfminer

I have followed a few tutorials around but I am not able to get this code block to run, I did the necessary switches from StringIO to BytesIO (I believe?)

I am unsure why 'banana' is printing nothing, I think the errors might be red herrings? is it something to do with me following a python2.7 tutorial and trying to translate it to python3?

```
errors: File "/Users/foo/PycharmProjects/Try/Pdfminer.py", line 28, in <module>
    banana = convert("A1.pdf")
  File "/Users/foo/PycharmProjects/Try/Pdfminer.py", line 19, in convert
    infile = file(fname, 'rb')
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

script

```
from io import BytesIO

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def convert(fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = BytesIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = file(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text

banana = convert("A1.pdf")
print(banana)
```

The same thing happens with this variant:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import BytesIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = BytesIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text

Banana = convert_pdf_to_txt("A1.pdf")
print(Banana)
```

I have tried searching for this (most of the pdfminer code is from [this](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python)) but having no luck.

Any insight is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Check out below answer which works in May 2020 and is very simple: from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text then text = extract_text('report.pdf') stackoverflow.com/a/61857301/7483211

Comment: `file()` is replaced by `open()` in Python 3. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962200/4054971

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There **is** a solution for **Python 3.5**: you need [pdfminer.six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer.six/20160614). Under **win10** I could easy install it with

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

You can check the installed version with

```
pdfminer.__version__
```

I haven't tested it intensively yet. But I could run the following code for the conversion **pdf→text** and  **pdf→html**

Comment: also, pdfminer.six seems maintained up to november 18! hooray.

Comment: @pyano You mention "could run the following code for the conversion pdf→text and pdf→html" BUT there is NO code following.
Working code example in May 2020 is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61857301/7483211

Comment: @Cornelius Roemer The code is just below in the next answer: 

Improved solution (Dez 2016)

Answer (score 13):

**Improved solution** (Dez 2016)

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter,TextConverter,XMLConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import io

def convert(case,fname, pages=None):
    if not pages: pagenums = set();
    else:         pagenums = set(pages);      
    manager = PDFResourceManager() 
    codec = 'utf-8'
    caching = True

    if case == 'text' :
        output = io.StringIO()
        converter = TextConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())     
    if case == 'HTML' :
        output = io.BytesIO()
        converter = HTMLConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)   
    infile = open(fname, 'rb')

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    convertedPDF = output.getvalue()  

    infile.close(); converter.close(); output.close()
    return convertedPDF

#//////////// main ///////////////////////
filePDF  = 'myDir//myPDF.pdf'     # input
fileHTML = 'myDir//myHTML.html'   # output
fileTXT  = 'myDir//myTXT.txt'     # output

case = "HTML"

if case == 'HTML' :
    convertedPDF = convert('HTML', filePDF, pages=[0,1])
    fileConverted = open(fileHTML, "wb", encoding="utf-8")
if case == 'text' :
    convertedPDF = convert('text', filePDF, pages=[0,1])
    fileConverted = open(fileTXT, "w", encoding="utf-8")

fileConverted.write(convertedPDF)
fileConverted.close()
#print(convertedPDF)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case on Python 3.7 I tried using it and it worked like a charm for me!

here is the code I used:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path_to_file):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path_to_file, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

Comment: which package did you install? the classis pdfminer states it doesnt support python3? https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/index.html

Comment: @benzkji You are right you need to install pdfminer.six for Python3. More details here
https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Answer (score 0):

The function `file()` was a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html) in Python 2.7. But it is not a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#file) in Python 3.5 anymore.

You should change `file()` into [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score -2):

pdfminer doesn't support **python version 3.5**. It works only in Python 2.6 or newer. I faced the same issue try using **python version 2.6** it will solve your problem.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use Python 3.8+ in 2023. This answer was written in 2016 and is outdated.