# Extracting text from a PDF file using Python 2.7 on Windows 7

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdftotext, pdfminer

I have been using PyPDF2 to extract the text included in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdn4t3qonrkado6/RevisionHistory70096702.pdf?dl=0) PDF file (generated with pdfTeX-1.40.0) using Python 2.7. It works fine but now i have to extract text from same [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6v8n8scfclc4fiw/RevisionHistory70307536.pdf?dl=0) generated with LibreOffice 4.3 and the result is this(not whole):

```
˜ ! ˜"!#$  %
˘ˇˆ˙˝
ˇ
˝%&˘
%'%
˛˚˛˜ !
"#$#"%$&
'##()˛˚˛
˛˚˛˜  !"#$#"%$%
*+!
```

This is my code:

```
    pdfFileObj = open(filePath, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    pageText = ""
    for pageID in range(0, pdfReader.numPages): 
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageID)
        pageText = pageText + "\n" + str(pageObj.extractText().encode('utf-8')))
    for line in pageText:
        extInfo = extInfo + line
    pdfFileObj.close()

    if string2search.replace(' ','') in extInfo:
        stringPresent = True
    else:
        stringPresent = False
```

Is there any simple working solution for windows machine ? 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-python) topic about this, but there is no solution. 
I have also tried to use PDFMiner from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python) topic, but I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec cant encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range (128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found solution for this.

1.- Download Xpdf tools for windows

2.- copy pdftotext.exe from xpdf-tools-win-4.00\bin32 to C:\Windows\System32 and also to C:\Windows\SysWOW64

3.- use code:

```
import subprocess

try:
    extInfo = subprocess.check_output('pdftotext.exe '+filePath + ' -',shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).strip()
except Exception as e:
    print (e) 

if string2search in extInfo:
    stringPresent = True
else:
    stringPresent = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the encoding before read

```
pdfFileObj = open(filePath, 'rb',encoding="utf-8") 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageText = ""
for pageID in range(0, pdfReader.numPages): 
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageID)
    pageText = pageText + "\n" + str(pageObj.extractText().encode('utf-8')))
for line in pageText:
    extInfo = extInfo + line
pdfFileObj.close()

if string2search.replace(' ','') in extInfo:
    stringPresent = True
else:
    stringPresent = False
```

Comment: I have tried it but i get error: "TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: try to "r" and not "rb"

Comment: Error: ''PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found"