# Django reading pdf files content

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pdf, pdfminer

I'm trying to find a plugin that reads text from PDF files. I found an old post about this issue and the answer was to use the following plugin : [pdfminer pluggin](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) 
However, this does not support python 3. Any suggestions ?

Comment: See this answer for python 3 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476759/2689986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyPDF2 is good for reading

check it out the this [Pdf Reader example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-pdf-files-in-python/)

Comment: Works fine, thanks!