# python pdfminer converts pdf file into one chunk of string with no spaces between words

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

I was using the following code mainly taken from DuckPuncher's answer to this post [Extracting text from a PDF file using PDFMiner in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python) to convert pdfs to text files:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str
```

The pdfs are downloaded and stored in my local directory using the following code and stored in my local directory. It worked fine.

```
import requests
url = 'link_to_the_pdf'
file_name = './name.pdf'
response = requests.get(url)
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

However, for some pdfs, the convert_pdf_to_txt() returned the content as almost one chunk of string with no spaces between words. For example, after downloading the following pdf from http://www.ece.rochester.edu/~gsharma/papers/LocalImageRegisterEI2005.pdf, and applying the convert_pdf_to_txt() function, I got a text file in which the words are not separated by spaces. An excerpt of the text file is

> 3Predominantmethodsinthelattergrouparefromcomputervisionarea,e.g.,plane+p
>   arallax4methodfor3-Dscenestructurecomputation.Inthispaper,weproposeanewlocalimageregistrationtechnique,intheﬁrstclass,basedonadaptiveﬁlteringtechniques.Adaptiveﬁltershavebeenutilizedsuccessfullyforsystemidentiﬁcationpurposesin1-D.

Can someone help me fix this problem please? Is it the format of this particular pdf that's causing the problem or something else, because with some other pdfs, the convert_pdf_to_txt() function is working fine.

Comment: The link you give  is broken (it's not blue colored completely) and leads to a non-PDF page. Can you give the link to the PDF-example you are interested in ?

Comment: @pyano Yes, sorry about the broken link. I have edited the link in the post. Now it should work. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfminer-users/KWGdoZ5-G04) some pdfs mark the entire text as figure and by default PDFMiner doesn't try to perform layout analysis for figure text.  To override this behavior the all_texts parameter needs to be set to True.

Here is an example that works for me based on [this post](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/03/exporting-data-from-pdfs-with-python/).

```
import io

import pdfminer
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

# Perform layout analysis for all text
laparams = pdfminer.layout.LAParams()
setattr(laparams, 'all_texts', True)

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=laparams)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

    # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()

    if text:
        return text


text = extract_text_from_pdf('test.pdf')
```