# Extract text from pdf converted from webpage using Pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, data-extraction, pypdf

I used chrome to convert a webpage into Pdf using save as pdf option. Now the problem is that when I extract the data from it using PyPDF2, it shows Null whereas it works on other pdf files easily. I know that I can extract data directly from the website but I want to understand why this is not working. It shows the correct number of pages but when I extracttext(), it shows nothing. Does anyone know what is the problem?
The link to the page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapping. I converted this webpage to pdf.

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('C:/Users/System/Desktop/Rapping - Wikipedia.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()
```

Comment: without code and the problem pdf file I doubt anyone can come with anything better than guesses

Answer (score 1):

PyPDF2 is highly unreliable for extracting text from pdf . as pointed out [here](https://realpython.com/pdf-python/) too.
it says :

> While PyPDF2 has .extractText(), which can be used on its page objects
>   (not shown in this example), it does not work very well. Some PDFs
>   will return text and some will return an empty string. When you want
>   to extract text from a PDF, you should check out the PDFMiner project
>   instead. PDFMiner is much more robust and was specifically designed
>   for extracting text from PDFs.

1. You could instead install and use [pdfminer](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/) using

   `pip install pdfminer`
2. or you can use another open source utility named `pdftotext` by [xpdfreader](https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html). instructions to use the utility is given on the page.

you can download the command line tools from [here](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html)
and could use the pdftotext.exe utility using `subprocess` .detailed explanation for using subprocess is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python)