# pdfminer3 extracts text from pdf without spaces

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

pdfminer3 is simple tool for extracting text from pdf. While browsing the cite for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530666/8523656), faced with the problem of spaces missing in extracted text.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is to specify laparams next way

```
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
```