# PDF - Split Single Words into Individual Lines - Python 3

Tags: python, pdf, text, pdfminer

I am trying to extract words from a PDF into individual lines, but can only do this with Text files as demonstrated below.

Moreover, the rule is that I cannot convert PDF files to TXT then perform this operation. It must be done on PDF files.

```
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)
```

If filename.txt has just "Hello World!", then this function returns:

```
Hello
World!
```

I need to do the same with searchable PDF files as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). There's loads of stuff you can do, including get line by line text from a PDF using `page.getText()`

Answer (score 1):

For the PDF, you should use pdf.miner or PyPDF2.

Here is a good article you can use to extract the text, and then you can use Anilkumar's method to extract line by line.

https://medium.com/@rqaiserr/how-to-convert-pdfs-into-searchable-key-words-with-python-85aab86c544f

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract texts (plain and containing PDF operators) from PDF document

Here is a sample code extracting all the above from all document pages.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""
try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Just want to outline, that text in PDFs usually do not come as "words", they look like commands to a conforming PDF viewer where and how to put a glyph. Which means a single word may be displayed by several commands. Read more on that in [PDF 1.7 docs sec.9 - Text](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=245)

Answer (score -1):

when I saw filename.txt I got confused.

Since you are working with PDF below link might be helpful. See it helps

[How to use PDFminer.six with python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494070/how-to-use-pdfminer-six-with-python-3)

Comment: This inserts individual characters into new lines for text files. I need to separate words from other words and insert them into new lines for PDF files.