# Extract text from PDF url with io and PyPDF2 gives no output

Tags: python, web-scraping, io, pdftotext, pdf-extraction

I'm trying to extract the text from the pdf url.
If I download the PDF I can easily extract the text with the function `slate`. However, when trying to import the pdf with `io` and extract the text, the output returned is just nothing. The code in attached below.

```
import requests, PyPDF2, io
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://www.poderjudicial.es/search/contenidos.action?action=accessToPDF&publicinterface=true&tab=AN&reference=e3ca421447bc6b71&encode=true&optimize=20210216&databasematch=AN'

response = requests.get(url)
f = io.BytesIO(response.content)

with f as data:
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(data)
    page = read_pdf.getPage(1)
    print(page.extractText())
```

I have tried a bunch of other functions but is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The first ten bytes of `response.content` are `b'%PDF-1.4\n%'`, so this seems a valid PDF file in the program. Did you try printing attribute `read_pdf.numPages`?

Answer (score 0):

It gives me the blank output as well. I am not sure why. But have you tried using [pdfminer3](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer3/) . It gives me the proper output as text.
The following code gives me the proper output for the file.

```
import requests
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

url = 'https://www.poderjudicial.es/search/contenidos.action?action=accessToPDF&publicinterface=true&tab=AN&reference=e3ca421447bc6b71&encode=true&optimize=20210216&databasematch=AN'

response = requests.get(url)
f = io.BytesIO(response.content)

with f as fh:

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

# close open handles
converter.close()
fake_file_handle.close()

print(text)
```

Check out this post as well
[How to use PDFminer.six with python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494070/how-to-use-pdfminer-six-with-python-3/56530666#56530666).