# Extracting text then saving to plain text file - TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, pdf, text, pdfminer

I am converting pdfs to text and got this code off a previous post:

[Extracting text from a PDF file using PDFMiner in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python)

When I print(text) it has done exactly what I want, but then I need to save this to a text file, which is when I get the above error.

The code follows exactly the first answer on the linked question. Then I:

```
text = convert_pdf_to_txt("GMCA ECON.pdf")

file = open('GMCAECON.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
file.write(text)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ebc6b7708d93> in <module>
----> 1 file = open('GMCAECON.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
  2 file.write(text)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I'm afraid it's probably something really simple but I can't figure it out. 
I want it to write the text to a text file with the same name, which I can then do further analysis on. Thanks.

Comment: Please, edit your post to include full traceback you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your third argument. Third positional argument accepted by `open` is buffering, not encoding.

Call `open` like this:

```
open('GMCAECON.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

and your problem should go away.

Comment: Thank you, that's great

Answer (score 1):

when you do `file = open('GMCAECON.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')` you pass positional arguments to `open()`. Third argument you pass is `encoding`, however the third argument it expect is `buffering`. You need to pass `encoding` as keyword argument, e.g.
`file = open('GMCAECON.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Note that it's much better is to use `with` context manager

```
with open('GMCAECON.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```