# Extract Numbers from a certain location in PDF files

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I'm trying to write a script to extract numbers from the "Total Deviation" graph in pdf files that looks like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiwmaeszLTmAhVEGTQIHcUQBccQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FHumphrey-visual-field-test-report-of-the-right-eye-showing-enlargement-of-the-blind-spot_fig1_308892761&psig=AOvVaw0J2aeXqvwYyWQXvziyyVvr&ust=1576394250599671). The reason I am trying to extract the information from the **location** of the graph rather than parsing the whole file and filtering it is that pdfminer exports the numbers in various and unpredictable patters (I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python) script). Sometimes it extracts the whole rows together and sometimes it extracts columns, so that's why I want to find a way to extract the numbers from various files in a consistent manner. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/). You can extract either text containing "pdf markdown" and than parse it with regular expressions for example:

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

pdf_markdown = ""

try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass

data = my_total_deviation_parser(pdf_markdown)
```