# How to Parse pdf from Django InMemoryUploadedFile?

Tags: python, django, pdf-parsing

I want to read files dynamically As i am giving pdf  file from  django the type of file it is having class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile' if i read the file it will have only bytes which is not understandable. Below is my code

```
def file(request):
    pdf = request.FILES['file']
    pdf1 = (pdf.read())
```

if i print the question i am getting bytes which is not understandable.so how to read pdfs from django dynamically and get text by using django

Comment: `response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf'); response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'`

Comment: I didn't want http response.My question is if i print pdf1 it will give bytes no text i want the text present in pdf

Comment: You can use the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26495057/10224558) to solve your problem

Comment: @MohdAbdulRaoof **if i print pdf1 it will give bytes no text i want the text present** - ??? it makes no sense. Now, if you want *PARSE* the PDF file in order to extract data, that's another question.

Comment: You are right but i am giving file from djangoapp it will come in pdf variable.After that line pdf1 is having bytes

Answer (score 1):

if you use the build in function .open you can handle it like a file and then access the text as mentioned in the comments or e.g. by using PyPDF2 and looping over the pages

```
import PyPDF2
pdf = request.FILES['file']
pdfFileObj =pdf.open()
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 
for p in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(p) 
    pdftext = pdftext+pageObj.extractText()
print(pdftext)
```

Comment: After searching everywhere. This worked for me. Thanks. I had to change it according to pypdf module. But rest was perfect.