# How to extract text from a pdf file

Tags: python, pdf

What is the best way to extract text from a pdf file.....
I have tried some
PyPDF2 -----> it only returns an empty string for all pages
tabula     -----> it returns a weird table of NaN
the pdf I am trying to **scrape** is
http://imdagrimet.gov.in/sites/default/files/daas_bulletin/Vaishali_46.pdf

Comment: refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-contents-of-pdf-using-ocr-optical-character-recognition/)

Comment: Please check the below link<br>
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use textract

```
import textract

text = textract.process("path_to_pdf")
```