# PDFminer only works if PDF is manually made searchable

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-extraction, pdfminer

I would like to extract text from PDF files using PDFminer and Jupyter Notebook.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6lmupe3dyunfgfk/test.pdf?dl=0) is an example of a PDF file from which I would like to extract text. When I use the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python), the output contains only the page one footer, while the rest of the document gets missed.

However, if I first use the Nitro Pro tool's OCR functionality to manually make the PDF file searchable, I am able to subsequently use the above Python code to extract all the text from the file.

I checked the PDFminer documentation to see if there is a parameter that I'm setting incorrectly, but I couldn't find anything on this issue. I would like to convert many files, so converting each file manually, using the Nitro Pro tool, is not feasible.

Comment: That is a scanned document, consisting solely of *images*.  Until OCR has been performed on it, there is simply no text to be extracted.

Comment: That's what I figured. I guess I was hoping that PDFminer would have an OCR option.