# Extract text from multiple PDFs and write to a single CSV

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, text-extraction, pdfminer

I want to loop through all the PDFs in a directory, extract the text from each one using PDFminer, and then write the output to a single CSV file. I am able to extract the text from each PDF individually by passing it to the function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python). I am also able to get a list of all the PDF filenames in a given directory. But when I try to put the two together and write the results to a single CSV, I get a CSV with headers but no data.

Here is my code:

```
import os
pdf_files = [name for name in os.listdir("C:\\My\\Directory\\Path") if name.endswith(".pdf")] #get all files in directory    
pdf_files_path = ["C:\\My\\Directory\\Path\\" + pdf_files[i] for i in range(len(pdf_files))] #add directory path

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['FileName','Text'])

for i in range(len(pdf_files)):
    scraped_text = convert_pdf_to_txt(pdf_files_path[i])
    df.append({ 'FileName': pdf_files[i], 'Text': scraped_text[i]},ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

The variables have the following values:

```
pdf_files: ['12280_2007_Article_9000.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9001.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9002.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9003.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9004.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9005.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9006.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9007.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9008.pdf', '12280_2007_Article_9009.pdf']

pdf_files_path: ['C:\\My\\Directory Path\\12280_2007_Article_9000.pdf', etc...]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [FileName, Text]
Index: []
```

Update: based on a suggestion from @AMC I checked the contents of scraped_text in the loop. For the Text column, it seems that I'm looping through the characters in the first PDF file, rather than looping through each file in the directly. Also, the contents of the loop are not getting written to the dataframe or CSV.

```
12280_2007_Article_9000.pdf E
12280_2007_Article_9001.pdf a
12280_2007_Article_9002.pdf s
12280_2007_Article_9003.pdf t
12280_2007_Article_9004.pdf  
12280_2007_Article_9005.pdf A
12280_2007_Article_9006.pdf s
12280_2007_Article_9007.pdf i
12280_2007_Article_9008.pdf a
12280_2007_Article_9009.pdf n
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], or at the very least the contents of the relevant variables.

Comment: As requested, I've added the contents of the relevant variables

Comment: Did you check the contents of `scraped_text` in the loop? At which point is the problem occurring?

Comment: why do you write out `scraped_text[i]` and not just `scraped_text`? The former gives you just a single character in the text; you want the whole text.

Comment: I checked the contents of the loop. For some reason, the variables are populated while in the loop, but the final CSV is empty.

Comment: The missing backslashes were a typo

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 9252-9253: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Just got the new error message and I've updated my answer to work around that. Check it out.

Comment: I'm deleting my comments just to keep the thread clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you don't need `pandas` for that. You can make it simpler by using the standard library [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Another thing that can be improved, if you are using Python 3.4+, is to replace `os` with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Here is an almost complete example:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path


folder = Path('c:/My/Directory/Path')
csv_file = Path('c:/path/to/output.csv')

with csv_file.open('w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    writer.writerow(['FileName', 'Text'])

    for pdf_file in folder.glob('*.pdf'):
        pdf_text = convert_pdf_to_txt(pdf_file).replace('\n', '|')
        writer.writerow([pdf_file.name, pdf_text])
```

Another thing to bear in mind is to be sure `pdf_text` will be a single line or else your `csv` file will be kind of broken. One way to work around that is to pick an arbitrary character to use in place of the new line marks. If you pick the pipe character, for example, than you can do something like this, prior to `writer.writerow`:

```py
pdf_text.replace('\n', '|')
```

It is not meant to be a complete example but a starting point. I hope it helps.

Comment: When I try that, I get a permissions error. [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: @b00kgrrrl most permissions denied issues can be solved by running the command with `sudo`

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the directory permissions, but you were right about the newline characters. That's what seems to be breaking the CSV.

Comment: I double checked the directory and it's correct. When I created an abbreviated version of the code for the purpose of posting a question, I inadvertently introduced an inconsistency.

Comment: As you requested, I've posted the full error message

Comment: Answer updated to work around `UnicodeEncodeError`. Seems like Windows uses cp1252 by default when opening a file for writing. The work around is to explicitly open the file with `enconding='utf-8'` instead.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'm still having issues with commas and newlines, but I can figure that out.

Comment: I'm glad to help.