# Error when trying to extract text from PDF using Python PDFMINER

Tags: python, pdf, pip, pdfminer

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF using Python's PDFMINER, but when I run the script below, I'm getting the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_pages' from 'pdfminer.high_level' (C:\Users\Willian Ambisis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\high_level.py)

Script:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

text = extract_text('report.pdf')
print(text)
```

I used this answer to build the script:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61857301/16487962

Comment: Did you check it? https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/570

Comment: I had already checked, I just left the "import pdfminer.high_level" but gave error again in extract_texttract saying it is not defined.

Comment: And even keeping the "from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text" points out the same error that generated my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Pytesseract and openCV instead. ([simple article](https://medium.com/@sandun.amarathunga/extract-text-from-files-and-images-using-pytessaract-and-opencv-aa26b615a7fb))

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract

filePath = ‘021-DO-YOU-WONDER-ABOUT-RAIN-SNOW-SLEET-AND-HAIL-Free-Childrens-Book-By-Monkey-Pen.pdf’
doc = convert_from_path(filePath)

path, fileName = os.path.split(filePath)
fileBaseName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(fileName)

for page_number, page_data in enumerate(doc):
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(page_data).encode(“utf-8”)
print(“Page # {} — {}”.format(str(page_number),txt))
```